# Read first three lines of a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following shell script to read in the first three lines of file and print them out to screen - it is not working correctly as it prints out lines 2,3,4 instead of lines 1,2,3 - What am I doing wrong ?

```
exec 6< rhyme.txt

while read file <&6 ;
do
        read line1 <&6
        read line2 <&6
        read line3 <&6

        echo $line1 
        echo $line2 
        echo $line3 
done

exec 6<&-
```

Thanks for your answers - I'm am aware of head command but want to use read and file descriptors to display the first three lines

Comment: Isn't 'head' a better alternative? Something like 'head -3 rhyme.txt'.

Comment: `head -3` works but it's clearer to use `head -n 3`

Comment: head -3 <filename> should be the best alternative here.

Comment: In case you really want to use a `while` and `read`, you can also use: `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < <(head -n 3 file)`

Answer (score 17):

You could also combine the head and while commands:

```
head -3 rhyme.txt | 
while read a; do
  echo $a; 
done
```

Comment: this is giving an error "var was modified in a subshell. That change might be lost."
https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2031

Answer (score 7):

It reads the first line

```
while read file <&6 ;
```

it reads the 2nd, 3rd and 4th line

```
read line1 <&6
read line2 <&6
read line3 <&6
```

If you want to read the first three lines, consider

> $ head -3 rhyme.txt

instead.

**Update**:

If you want to use `read` alone, then leave out the `while` loop and do just:

```
exec 6< rhyme.txt

read line1 <&6
read line2 <&6
read line3 <&6

echo $line1 
echo $line2 
echo $line3 

exec 6<&-
```

or with a loop:

```
exec 6< rhyme.txt

for f in `seq 3`; do
    read line <&6
    echo $line 
done

exec 6<&-
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a `read` in the  `while` loop, which eats the first line.

You could use a simpler `head -3` to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I got similar task, to obtain sample 10 records and used `cat` and `head` for the purpose.
Following is the one liner that helped me `cat FILE.csv| head -11`
Here, I used '11' so as to include header along with the data.